# How to write an if statement which reads: 'if is this custom post type or a child of it do the following'?

Tags: custom-post-types, bbpress

Basically, I would like to activate a CSS class only if the current page is a certain custom post type (e.g. `?bbp_forum=technology`) or if the current page is a child of that custom post type.

**EDIT:**

The first custom post type is called '`bbp_forum`.' Each '`bbp_forum`' can have a '`bbp_topic`' (which is another custom post type).

Like it is described in this picture:

[image]

I used to do the following in order to assign the class `current` to the current '`bbp_forum`'s link:

```
        <?php
            global $post;
            $the_post_ID = $post->ID;
            $cat_posts = get_posts('post_type=bbp_forum&posts_per_page=-1');
            var_dump($the_post_ID);
        ?>
        <?php foreach ( $cat_posts as $post ) : ?>
            <li <?php if ( $post->ID == $the_post_ID )  echo 'class="current"'; ?>>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </li>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

but it doesn't work for a child of the '`bbp_forum`'

Comment: Why don't you explain the use-cases for your custom post type and especially for the child post types. Are they the same types as their parents, or different?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel OK I updated my question please see my EDIT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally got the answer:

```
        <?php
            global $post;
            $the_post_parent = $post->post_parent;
            $the_post_ID = $post->ID;
            $cat_posts = get_posts('post_type=bbp_forum&posts_per_page=-1');
            print_r($post_parent);
        ?>
        <?php foreach ( $cat_posts as $post ) : ?>
            <li <?php if ( $post->ID == $the_post_ID || $post->ID == $the_post_parent ) echo 'class="current"'; ?>>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I would appreciate if someone explain it to me.

Comment: its just the same as you did before but instead of just checking if it matches the current post, it check if it matches the current posts parent.

Comment: @Bainternet yeah I figured out later. I'm a bit slow. Thanks man.